# How to take the output of grep and write it to a new file

Tags: c, file, grep

I want to take the output of the grep command on a file, create a new file and save that grep output to the new created file, can someone please point me to the right direction in how I would do that?

Comment: Use `popen()`, `fgets()` and `fputs()`.

Comment: Alternatively, `grep foo > myfile.txt`

Answer (score 2):

The path you choose depends a great deal on how simple you want it to be.

Perhaps the simplest method is the use of `system`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main (void) {
        system ("grep a *.c >outfile.txt");
        return 0;
}
```

though you also could construct the command *dynamically* if you have different arguments to `grep` or a non-fixed output file.

---

Beyond that, you could use `popen()` (if available on your implementation - it's not mandated by ISO but is instead a POSIX thing) along with `fgets()` or `fgetc()` to read the output of that command and do whatever you want with it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
    int chr;

    FILE *echo = popen ("echo hello there", "r");
    if (echo != NULL) {
        while ((chr = fgetc (echo)) != EOF)
            putchar (chr);
        fclose (echo);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

The next step up from there may be to not rely on an external `grep` at all but instead include something like [PCRE](http://www.pcre.org/) (Perl-compatible regular expressions) into your own code, giving you much finer control over what happens.